# How to use Application Verifier on Windows 7 without Administrator rights

Tags: windows

I tried to use Application Verifier, but without Administartor rights I can't add application (menu item File->Add Application disabled).

I've read this article, but it doesn't help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx